# Vstack with merged cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vstack

I want to use the formula vstack on an array to combine columns from different worksheets, it works perfect on column H and beyond but on the columns that have stacked cells(D to G), I got error #SPILL!
[image: vstack]

Is there a way to avoid it without using vba? Thanks!

Comment: So `D5:D15` for example is one single merged cell? And what do you want to show in that cell? If you have multiple values maybe consider to `TEXTJOIN()` them with `CHAR(10)` as a delimiter? Maybe add more context on what your data should look like too. Off-topic: Don't use merged cells. They are evil!

Comment: Thanks for your reply, yes, D5 to D15 is a merged cell that I want to stack, I got sheet2 to sheet5 on column D data on merged cells, I want to show all that data stacked on sheet1, on cells H and forward, cause the cells are not merged, it works fine, but it doesn't work with merged cells D to G. Unfortunately I have to use merged cells to keep the format on the imported data :(

Comment: So can't you then simply use `=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),,<YourArrayOfValues>)`? I'm not sure if that's what you want, because you still haven't shown how you'd like the result to look like.

Comment: Can imagine sg. like this. Get the cells in a separate part of the sheet(but data will remain there), Join them with CountA Textjoin in the merged range.

Comment: What's the reason for them being merged? can't you simply unmerge?

Comment: Thanks for your comments and input, the reason for the cells to be merged is to group the data in the following cells, the data in cells "I" and forward share the common data of cells D to G

Answer (score 1):

This is from Microsoft site
(https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/-spill-error-spill-into-merged-cell-4a220ecc-b830-4e22-b8a6-4b86f6cf6507)

And a quote from it:

> #SPILL! error - Spill into merged cell
> Excel for Microsoft 365 Excel for Microsoft 365 for Mac Excel for the web Excel for iPad More...
>
> Spilled array formulas cannot spill into merged cells. Please un-merge the cells in question, or move the formula to another range that doesn't intersect with merged cells.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to solve it using another formula or system? Thanks!

Comment: This i only post to be sure of it. @JvdV comments are on the subject.